# Angular 4 Reactive Form Enable Field After refresh page

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive from declared in angular 4

```
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  "id": [user ? user.id : ""],
  "profile": this.fb.group({
    "email": [user && user.profile.email ? { value: user.profile.email, disabled: true } : "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
  }),

  "username": [user && user.username ? { value: user.username, disabled: true } : "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, GlobalValidator.usernameFormat])],
})
```

By default if my form is filled out with the data the form field is disabled (email, username).
The problem that I am facing is, If I refresh my page the form field appears enabled.

(EDITED)

```
    ngOnInit() {
       this.buildForm()
       if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id) {
         this.service.getUser(Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id)).subscribe((user) => {
          this.buildForm(user)
        }) 
       }
     }
     buildForm(user?:any){
       this.userForm = this.fb.group({
         "id": [user ? user.id : ""],
         "profile": this.fb.group({
          "email": [user && user.profile.email ? { value: user.profile.email, disabled: true } : "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      }),

      "username": [user && user.username ? { value: user.username, disabled: true } : "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, GlobalValidator.usernameFormat])],
    })
```

}

Comment: I'd suggest providing a bit more context so we can see where you're running everything.  Also, it helps if you make a demo using https://stackblitz.com.  Just click Angular and it creates a project that you can drop in your code and replicate the issue.

Comment: Where is this `user` fetched from?

Comment: Is there any error at the browser's console?

Comment: no, no errors in the console, just after refresh the browser tab, my form fields disabled, appears enabled

Comment: @mtpultz Is dificult to reproduce in stackblitz.com because happens if I refresh the browser tab

Comment: Where are you invoking the `FormBuilder` is it in `ngOnInit`?  When you refresh and fetch the data where are you doing that with respect to instantiating the FormBuilder?  It would be great to see more code otherwise, everyone is just guessing.  If you drop it into stackblitz everyone can at least see how everything is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix this issue I change my code :

before:

```
"username": [user && user.username ? { value: user.username, disabled: true } : "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, GlobalValidator.usernameFormat])],
```

after:

```
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
username : this.fb.control("")
})
if(user){
this.userForm.get("username").setValue(user.username)
this.userForm.get("username").disable()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but calling this.userForm.get("username").disable() did not fixed it because I was reloading my view (using router.navigate()).

In my case I had to reset my form before reloading:

this.userForm = undefined;
this.router.navigate([path]);